# Fonts not loading on IE 9 and 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts

I am using three custom fonts on a site, but no matter how many ways I try to load them, they will not load in internet explorer 9 and 11 (and possible other versions as well)! I have consulted lots of similar questions on the site, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Here's what I have so far:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bourton';
    src: url('fonts/BourtonBase.eot');
    src: url('fonts/BourtonBase.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/BourtonBase.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bourton Script';
    src: url('fonts/BourtonScriptBold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/BourtonScriptBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/BourtonScriptBold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bourton Line Bold';
    src: url('fonts/BourtonLineBold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/BourtonLineBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/BourtonLineBold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

The paths are correct relative to the stylesheet this code is posted in.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which IE version?

Comment: @IgnacioAra - IE 11, just added to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Add IE fix in first position, like in this example (second one of your list):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bourton Script';
    src: url('fonts/BourtonScriptBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    src: url('fonts/BourtonScriptBold.eot');
         url('fonts/BourtonScriptBold.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like this is working. It's very slow for me to test this solution because I am waiting in a queue with browserling to simulate internet explorer. Do you see any other glaring mistakes in my code? Also, the issue also exists in IE 9